# Space Invaders Killing the Enemy

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, shift

Currently im working on a Space Invaders project and the programming language is based off Java but not completely. It doesn't have all the commands like Java so its just like simple language.
So to program this, i code in simple code. Such as using if statements and for loop.

So the problem i am stuck on is how to make the player's bullet kill the enemyAI
I can't get the enemy to destroy itself.
I've tried many methods but i cant seem to make it work.

So here was my first method :
Making four single arrays

```
int[] enemyPosX 
int[] enemyPosY
int[] enemyDirX
int[] enemyDirY
```

And from that i make a nested loop which generates a grid, width of 10 and height of 3.
And once i have done that i made it move from from left to right and once its reached to the end of the width of the game, the direction changes and moves down by one.

```
int width = 10;
int height = 3;
int numEnemy = width * height;

int[] enemyPosX new int[numEnemy];
int[] enemyPosY new int[numEnemy];
int[] enemyDirX new int[numEnemy];
int[] enemyDirY new int[numEnemy];


void main() {
    for(int x = 0; x < width; x = x + 1) {
         for(int y = 0; y < height; y = y + 1) {
              enemyPosX[x] = x * height * 5;
              enemyPosY[y] = y * height * 15;
              enemyDirX[x] = 5;
              enemyDirY[y] = 5;
         }
    }
}
```

After doing this i generated information for the bullet. When the player fires it.
By the dimensions of the game area is 800 by 800.

```
for(int i = 0; i < firedBullets; i = i + 1) {
    setColor(0, 0, 0);
    fillRect(bulletPosX[i], bulletPosY[i], 6, 30);
    bulletPosY[i] = bulletPosY[i] - 5;
    if(bulletPosY[i] < -50) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < firedBullets; j = j + 1) {
            bulletPosX[j - 1] = bulletPosX[j];
            bulletPosY[j - 1] = bulletPosY[j];
            bulletDirX[j - 1] = bulletDirX[j];
            bulletDirY[j - 1] = bulletDirY[j];
        }
        firedBullets = firedBullets - 1;

    }
}
void onKeyPressed (int code) {
    if(code == 37) {
        playerPosX = playerPosX - 15;
    }
    if(code == 39) {
        playerPosX = playerPosX + 15;
    }
    if(code == 32) {
        if(firedBullets < maxBullets) {
            bulletPosX[firedBullets] = playerPosX + 46;
            bulletPosY[firedBullets] = playerPosY - 30;
            bulletDirX[firedBullets] = 5;
            bulletDirY[firedBullets] = 5;

            firedBullets = firedBullets + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I also did this for 2D arrays but i can't actually seem to make it work.
How can i make it so when the bullet from the player hits the enemyAI it will kill the enemy.
Can you guys make simple code without using any Java commands.
Just do them in for loops and use maths ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you figured out how to do [collision detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) yet?

Comment: I think to detect the collection of the bullet and enemyAI is by the position.
So if the position of the bullet is greater than the enemyAI position then it has collided.
Or is it not ?
I only thing i stuck on is how to make it disappear (kill)

Comment: How are you storing the enemies?

Comment: The first method was storing it in a 1D array which can be seen above and the second method was storing it in a 2D array.